# How can we paginate multiple sqlalchemy querysets into one in Flask api

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two SQLalchemy quesrysets(q1, q2). let us say q1 has 5 items and q2 has 3 items. I want to write a single api with pagination.If my page size is 2. i should get the following results

```
q1=1,2,3,4,5 
q2=6,7,8

page 1 = 1,2
page 2 = 3,4
page 3 = 5,6
page 4 = 7,8
```

Can someone please help

Comment: Have you tried doing a [Union](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.union) on the two queries to produce a single query and then using the standard pagination from Flask-Sqalchemy on that query?

Comment: The problem with union is that it does not guarantee order of results. @pjcunningham

Comment: If your database allows it you can do an order_by on a union. Create a calculated column on both queries. Query 1 has calculated value 0, query 2 has calculated value 1 and then sort on the calculated column.

Comment: Mysql is our database. can you share any example links for the same. I have one more concern with that approach because whenever a api hits occurs it would call both queries and hence a performance issue.

Comment: I am looking some general solution or logic  which will dynamically handle this. like when first queryset item ends it would automatically starts adding items from second queryset and so on

Comment: `q1 = UserAccountModel.query.with_entities(UserAccountModel, order2.label("order")).filter(UserAccountModel.id > 5).order_by(UserAccountModel.id.desc())`  I tried with the calulated approach as in the example. calculated filed name "order" for q1 is 1 and q2 is 2. `union(users_q1, users_q2).order_by('order').all()` the problem with this is that it individual order of items in q1 or q2 are not retained. @pjcunningham

Comment: Taken to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232696/flask-union-pagination)

Comment: Checked your reference but how can i do the same in sqlalchemy terms @pjcunningham